# PHP: substract values of 2 arrays of different length

Tags: php, arrays

Well, I've got two following arrays:

```
$incomesArr = [
  ['1605564000' => 121],
  ['1605736800' => 3.50],
];

$expensesArr = [
  ['1605736800' => 3.50],
  ['1605736800' => 3.50],
  ['1605564000' => 28],
  ['1605936000' => 50]
];
```

As you can see from the variable names, these are the expenses and incomes for the current date (it is a timestamp). All I want to do is to generate the "Revenue" data by substracting value of `$expensesArr` from `$incomesArr` with corresponding date, and if there is no date, then substract from `0`. Also, if there is no corresponding date in the `$expensesArr`, then substract nothing (or 0).

Basically, I want to achieve the following result:

```
['1605564000', 93]; // 121 - 28 = 93
['1605736800', -3.50] // 3.50 - 3.50 - 3.50 (since both expenses are for the same date)
['1605936000', -50] // 0 - 50, since there is no income for that day.
```

Please note, that the output result should be in the `['key', 'value']` format, not the `['key' => 'value']`, since I send these data to jQuery Flot (displaying graphs).

I carry about the performance, since there may be kind of significant amount of data and the best way for me to achieve this is without `foreach` loop, however if it is the only possible option, then `foreach` it is!

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

P.S. If it would help, then I do this in Laravel, however I don't think that there is a special helper exactly for that, since I already examined the Laravel documentation multiple times :)

My previous attempt was a bit confusing and scary, but here it is:

```
$newArr = array_merge([$incomesArr, $expensesArr]);

foreach ($incomesArr as $k => $v){
  $sub = $v - $expensesArr[$k];
  // this is like : array1[1]-array2[1]
}

$finalArr = [];
foreach($newArr as $key => $value) {
  var_dump($value);
  foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
    $finalArr[$key] = ($val[$key] ?? 0) - ($val[$key] ?? 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code and attempts, what is the errors or challenges that you got while your trying to accomplish this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$incomesArr = [
  ['1605564000' => 121],
  ['1605736800' => 3.50],
];

$expensesArr = [
  ['1605736800' => 3.50],
  ['1605736800' => 3.50],
  ['1605564000' => 28],
  ['1605936000' => 50]
];


// get data

$dataArr = [];

    foreach([-1 => $expensesArr, 1 => $incomesArr] as $ratio => $list){
        foreach($list as $value){
        $time = key($value);
        $dataArr[$time] = ($dataArr[$time] ?? 0) + ($value[$time] * $ratio);
        }
    }


// convert to your format

$finalArr = [];

    foreach($dataArr as $time => $value){
    $finalArr []= [$time, $value];
    }


print_r($finalArr);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1605736800
            [1] => -3.5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1605564000
            [1] => 93
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1605936000
            [1] => -50
        )

)
```

Comment: I like how this is all done together in a single loop.

Comment: I never realized I could use multiple arguments inside the foreach loop as array of arguments...

Answer (score 1):

```php
$incomesArr = [
  ['1605564000' => 121],
  ['1605736800' => 3.50],
];

$expensesArr = [
  ['1605736800' => 3.50],
  ['1605736800' => 3.50],
  ['1605564000' => 28],
  ['1605936000' => 50]
];

$tmp = [];
$final = [];
foreach ($incomesArr as $pair)
{
    foreach ($pair as $date => $amount)
    {
        $tmp[$date] = ($tmp[$date] ?? 0) + $amount;
    }
}

foreach ($expensesArr as $pair)
{
    foreach ($pair as $date => $amount)
    {
        $tmp[$date] = ($tmp[$date] ?? 0) - $amount;
    }
}

print_r($tmp);

foreach ($tmp as $date => $amount)
{
    $final[] = [$date, $amount];
}

print_r($final);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [1605564000] => 93
    [1605736800] => -3.5
    [1605936000] => -50
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1605564000
            [1] => 93
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1605736800
            [1] => -3.5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1605936000
            [1] => -50
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would split it into two functions like so:

```
$incomesArr = [
    ['1605564000' => 121],
    ['1605736800' => 3.50],
];

$expensesArr = [
    ['1605736800' => 3.50],
    ['1605736800' => 3.50],
    ['1605564000' => 28],
    ['1605936000' => 50]
];

function getTotalByKey($inputArray, $inputKey)
{
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($inputArray as $subArray)
        foreach ($subArray as $key => $value) {
            $sum += $key === $inputKey ? $value : 0;
        }
    return $sum;
}

function getProfitByKey($incomesArray, $expensesArray, $key){
    return getTotalByKey($incomesArray, $key) - getTotalByKey($expensesArray, $key);
}

$profit = getProfitByKey($incomesArr, $expensesArr, 1605736800); // Outputs -3.5
```